# Profiling a C++ program using high_resolution_clock

Tags: c++, profiling

I want to profile my C++ program, and used [high_resolution_clock](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now/) for that purpose. A sample code for that matter is provided as an example. I tried three different ways.

**Example 1**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

unsigned int ttime = 0;
int main(){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(i < 10000000){
        high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        j += i;     
        i++;
        high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto tm_duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
        ttime += tm_duration;
    }
    cout << "Took " << ttime << " microseconds " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This [example](http://cpp.sh/5bkrc) use clock inside the loop and works well, gives results as expected.

**Example 2**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

unsigned int ttime = 0;
int main(){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    while(i < 10000000){
        j += i;     
        i++;
    }
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto tm_duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    ttime += tm_duration;
    cout << "Took " << ttime << " microseconds " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This [example](http://cpp.sh/5yglp) shows `0` time, which I doubt about.

**Example 3**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

unsigned int ttime = 0;
int main(){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    while(i < 10000000){
        j += i;     
        i++;
        high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto tm_duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
        ttime += tm_duration;
    }   
    cout << "Took " << ttime << " microseconds " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This [example](http://cpp.sh/3hwhw6) shows `3792420263` microseconds which I also doubt about.

What is the problem in `example 2` and `example 3`. Which out of the three is correct.

Answer (score 2):

**Example 2** gets optimized by compiler so if you want to see loop run time, you should disable any compiler optimizations.

**Example 3** makes no sense since you add a difference time in every loop and the result is number that says nothing about loop run time. Furthermore you encounter many overflows during your loop with 32-bit `unsigned int ttime`.

So the best solution for profiling real code is **Example 2**. Do not worry about your zero output, if you add any "reasonable code" between `t1` and `t2` creation, you get better number.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler optimizes those loops away. If you disable Optimizations in the Options menu it will show plausible values.